# Generate S3 Put URL Per Request

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

How can I generate pre-signed S3 URLs for uploading on a per-request basis from NodeJS?  I am storing the bucket name, region, IAM User key, and IAM User secret for multiple buckets.  Unfortunately, all of the examples I'm finding show the AWS config being updated globally:

All of the examples I am finding show the following `config.*` lines which scare me:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY});
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';
```

This code appears to set the config globally... which would destroy every subsequent request OR requests that might be happening simultaneously.

I'd like to load **everything** dynamically, from the stored IAM credentials and bucket name, and generate the URL using the stored information:

```
var aws     = require('aws-sdk'),
    express = require('express'),
    Repo    = require('../../models');

function createUrl (req, res, next) {

    var endpointId  = (req.params.endpointId || '').toUpperCase(),
        fileType    = req.body.type || '',
        fileName    = req.body.name || '',
        fileSize    = req.body.size || '';

    Repo.Endpoints.findById(endpointId, function (err, item) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!item) { return next(new Error('Unknown endpoint')); }

        var config = {
            accessKeyId     : item.iamUserAccessKey,
            secretAccessKey : item.iamUserSecret,
            region          : item.bucketRegion
        };

        var params = {
            Bucket      : item.bucketName,
            Key         : fileName,
            ContentType : fileType
        };

        var s3 = new aws.S3(config);
        s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, url) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.send({ url: url });
        });
    });
}
```

However, this code just feels wrong... like I'm missing something critical.

**Update 10/13/2015 19:33 EST**
The URL is generated however, I'm getting an error when I try to do a POST:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://<%URL FROM SERVER%>. No 'Access-Control
-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:
//localhost:4003' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP 
status code 403.
```

The CORS policy on the bucket is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:4003</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://lvh.me:4003</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Origin</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: You can't pre sign a URL because the signature covers http headers too

Comment: @RhythmicFistman : That's strange, because the code above does yield a URL.  If you cannot pre-sign a URL then what is Amazon returning?

Comment: Yes, you can pre-sign a PUT URL, but they are more delicate than pre-signed GET URLs since more information goes into the signing of a PUT and the request you make has to match the request you anticipated when signing.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Any idea where I can find info on how to do it?  The code above generates a URL however the client gets a CORS error when trying to do a put or post.

Comment: CORS error != invalid signature.  Is CORS configured on the bucket?

Comment: iirc, "localhost" doesn't work with CORS.  Try accessing your local site using `http://lvh.me:4003` (it resolves to 127.0.0.1 like localhost) and once you've got that working, use that in the CORS policy, instead, for testing.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Same results: `Origin 'http://lvh.me:4003' is therefore not allowed access.`  And the header config does have `<AllowedOrigin>http://lvh.me:4003</AllowedOrigin>`.

Comment: We've drifted from the topic of your original question.  You will want to capture the response headers and troubleshoot from there.  What you are talking about now sounds like the browser may have cached a pre-flight response.