# Upload to S3 without local keys?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-s3

What is the best way to upload from AngularJS to S3 without passing the access key or secret down to the client?  I have a friend who is trying to accomplish this by creating a pre-signed URL on the server (NodeJS & Express) and then sending the URL to the client for upload.  He's claiming it's failing due to CORS but he CAN upload using the sdk from the same AngularJS app & browser.

**Update for Clarity**
The tricky part is they cannot store anything in an environment variable AND **each bucket has different credentials**.  They're storing info on 10-20 buckets / regions / IAM users and need the end user to select the bucket BY NAME on the client.  This means they cannot store anything globally.  The server must be able to generate something for the client to use per each request.

His original question:
[Generate S3 Put URL Per Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111135/generate-s3-put-url-per-request)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using an [IAM Instance Profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html) for your ec2 server. That way you don't have to provide your access & secret key, because any call done via the AWS SDK will be authenticated via the instance profile permissions. Either of this, in order! authenticate aws api calls:

1. `In system environment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.`
2. `In the Java system properties: aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey.`
3. `In the default credentials file (the location of this file
   varies by platform).`
4. `In the instance profile credentials, which exist within the instance metadata associated with the IAM role for the EC2 instance.`

Note the instance profile creds are checked last!

More info [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/credentials.html)

Comment: Don't think they can go this route.  They're storing info on 10-20 buckets / regions / IAM users and need the end user to select the bucket BY NAME on the client.  This means they cannot store anything globally.

Comment: Using IAM Instance Profile does not mean you need to store anything globally. All you need to do is launch the ec2 instance / server with an instance profile which has access to the buckets.

Comment: But setting environment variables for the key & secret would assume all buckets have the same security, which they will not.  Each bucket has different credentials.